# How tradingview gets data to refresh price?

Tags: javascript, api, tradingview-api

I am javascript developer and this question is out of curiosity. Does anyone know how tradingview gets price data?

I checked chrome network's tab, but there is no api which is refreshing data. So how they have created webpage where price is changed every second without refreshing the page.

I am trying to understand how they implement continuous price change functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They use a WebSocket Stream coming from `wss://data.tradingview.com/socket.io/websocket` and it provides a [UDF](https://www.tradingview.com/wiki/Data_sources) formatted stream (which is simply a specific way of providing JSON data in a standardized way so the charting library can understand it).